# ACTION_GET_CONTENT , Получить путь к файлам изображений и аудио

Tags: android, android-intent

Есть интент

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Есть обработка результата

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("!!! data.getData()",data.getData().toString());
    Log.i("!!! getPath()",data.getData().getPath());
}
```

Выбираю три разных файла

Вывод:

аудио файл

```
I/!!! data.getData(): content://media/external/audio/media/21260
I/!!! getPath(): /external/audio/media/21260
```

какой то файл

```
I/!!! data.getData(): file:///storage/extSdCard/downloads/dd-wrt.trx
I/!!! getPath(): /storage/extSdCard/downloads/dd-wrt.trx
```

изображение

```
I/!!! data.getData(): content://media/external/images/media/21534
I/!!! getPath(): /external/images/media/21534
```

и документ doc

```
I/!!! data.getData(): file:///storage/extSdCard/downloads/cv.doc
I/!!! getPath(): /storage/extSdCard/downloads/cv.doc
```

Дело в том, что этот путь (getPath()) передается в другой метод для загрузки файла на сервер, и при передаче, в случае с аудио файлом,"/external/audio/media/21260", выдает fileNotFound .Ткните носом в документацию, как получить пути к самим файлам изображений и аудио?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос можно закрывать. Для моих целей мне подходит метод

```
String getFilePathFromContentPath(Uri uri) {
    String filePath = null;
    if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA},
                null,
                null,
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        filePath = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        filePath = uri.getPath();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```